# Slider revolution and fancybox-3

Tags: fancybox-3

I try to implement FancyBox 3 in a carousel from the plugin slider revolution. The next code works well with FancyBox 2 but with fancyBox 3 the arrows not work. I want o know if someone has the solution.

Link: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/using-fancybox-with-slider-revolution/

Code that works well in FancyBox2 but not shows the arrows in fancyBox3

```
/* change revapi1 to whatever API name is being used for your slider */
var api = revapi1;

/* no need to edit below unless you want to change the default FancyBox settings */
api.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

    jQuery(this).find('.fancybox').each(function() {

        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if(!$this.is('a')) $this = $this.removeClass('fancybox').find('a');

        $this.addClass('fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({

            /* begin FancyBox options */
            width: 'auto',            
            height: 'auto',
            autoSize: true,
            aspectRatio: true,
            fitToView: true,
            autoCenter: true,
            scrolling: 'no',
            onClosed: function() {api.revresume()}

        }).on('click', function() {api.revpause()});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fancyBox v3 uses `data-fancybox` attribute for grouping instead of `rel`.

So, replace

```
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
```

with

```
.attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery')
```

Simple demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyYryd?editors=1010

btw, v3 does not have these options you are using and `afterClose` callback is used instead of `onClosed`

Comment: Hi The problem is not fancybox3. The problem that i have is the integration with the plugin slider revolution. FancyBox2 work ok but not the 3. I have a example in this page http://www.viajaydescubre.com/fancybox3/ Can you take a look please. Thanks

Comment: Looks like this slider is just not optimised to work nicely with lightbox-type scripts. Maybe consider alternatives - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/eWVyVg and https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/gWvorB